# How to parametrise or make functions generic in Python?

Tags: python, generics, closures

I am using a Python library (`APScheduler`) that requires some function handlers. All these handlers functions are almost the same. The only difference is a "constant" (as in, logic is the same; only the constant used to reference some data structures is different).

I would like to have a single generic function for all the handlers such that I can minimise my code or not having to add new functions when I add new types. Moreover, this enables me to have my types declared in a configuration file.

In Javascript this would be possible like this:

```
function staticFunction(args) {
    // ... this function I have to parameterise
};

function factory(type) {
    return function(args) {
        // ... this function is parametrised with "type"
    };
}

addHandler(staticFunction)
addHandler(factory("apples"));
addHandler(factory("oranges"));
```

How do I do the same in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do exactly the same thing in Python; you can create a nested function that'll have access to `type` as a closure:

```
def factory(type):
    def nested(args):
        # do something with `type`
    return nested

add_handler(factory('apples'))
```

There are more ways you can bind a parameter to a callable; you could use a `lambda` to proxy the function call:

```
def static_function(type, args):
    # ...

add_handler(lambda args: static_function('apples', args))
```

or you could use a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to bind arguments to a callable:

```
from functools import partial

add_handler(partial(static_function, 'apples'))
```